# Update element offset during css animation jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, animation, offset

I'm trying to get current offset of an element during css animation.
I'm firing animation trough jquery like this:

```
$('.left').css('margin-left', '50%');
```

Of course element got all transitions in CSS so .css turns into animation.
Then i'm trying to obtain current offset like that:

```
var left = $( ".left" );
var Loffset = left.offset();
console.log(Loffset.left);
```

The problem is that offset is not autamatically updated during the animation. And i wanna catch element in certain position.

Thnx in advance!

Comment: Do you want to get `offset` of element when animating?

Comment: yes i would like to keep it updated on every pixel - cause i need to compare it to other value, and when it meet the value then fire something

Answer (score 2):

You can get current offset of element using `step` property in jquery `animate()`.

```js
$("div").animate({
    "margin-left": "50%"
},{
    duration: 3000,
    step: function(){
        console.log($(this).offset().left);
    }
});
```

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: yes i know, but css animations works better for me and got better performance. Just trying to find something like "css animation in progress" event

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, to do this.
First of all, i've made a function which fires continously:

```
var myFunction = function() {
        var left = $('.left');
        var Loffset = left.offset();
        console.log(Loffset.left);
        if (windowWidthQuarter == Loffset.left) {
            /* here goes code */        
        }
};
var timer = setInterval(myFunction, 0);
```

It's checking offset every 0 miliseconds (non-stop).
Then, when the Transition is over i shut it down:

```
$(".left").on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function(){
     clearTimeout(timer);
});
```